# How to display various parsed  XML files in android?

Tags: android, xml-parsing, saxparser

I am building an application in which one of my modules consists of weather forecasting.I am using SAX Parser and as of now,I am parsing the XML file and obtaining the result of a single place and here it goes:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.saxmain);
    
    ScrollView MyScrollView = new ScrollView(this);
    LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
    
    layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    MyScrollView.addView(layout);
    
    try {
        
        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(
                "http://192.168.1.31:81/Udayavani/android/weather/weather.php?city=mumbai");

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
        
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

 /* Get result from MyXMLHandler TagList Object */
    taglist = MyXMLHandler.sitesList;

      
    
    for (int i = 0; i <26; i++) {
        texts[i] = new TextView(this);
        texts[i].setText(""+i);
        texts[i].setTypeface(kannada);
        layout.addView(texts[i]);
        
        
    }
    /** Set the result text in textview and add it to layout */
        texts[0].setText("Current= "+taglist.getCurrent().get(0));
        texts[1].setText("Temp= "+taglist.getTemp().get(0));
        texts[2].setText("Humidity= "+taglist.getHumidity().get(0));
        texts[3].setText(""+taglist.getWind_condition().get(0));
        texts[4].setText(""+taglist.getIcon().get(0));
       int j=0; 
       int k=5;
        while(k<20){
        texts[k].setText("----------------------------------"); 
        k++;
        texts[k].setText("Day= "+taglist.getDay().get(j));
        k++;
        texts[k].setText("Condition= "+taglist.getCondition().get(j));
        k++;
        texts[k].setText("Low= "+taglist.getLow().get(j));
        k++;
        texts[k].setText("High= "+taglist.getHigh().get(j));
        k++;
        texts[k].setText("Icon= "+taglist.getIcon().get(j));
        k++;
        j++;
        if(j>=5){
            j=0;
               }
             }
    

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(MyScrollView);

  }
    }
```

My question to SO is that,could anybody please help me to get the parsed Xml file of the various cities? I have the URL for almost all the cities and I can get that,just by changing the city name in the end of my URL(say weather.php?city=auckland) which I have mentioned in my code.I am starting with the ListView and I have around 20-30 cities stored in the ListView as list-contents.Whenever I click on the particular place I want to get the parsed XMl file of that particular city.

Anyone please guide me on this.

Thanks

### EDITED:

xml contents:

```
            <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <weather>
<current_conditions>
    <current>ಹೊಗೆಯಾವೃತ</current>
    <temp>95</temp>
    <humidity>Humidity: ೨೩%</humidity>
    <wind_condition>Wind: ಪೂ at 13 km/h</wind_condition>
    <icon>smoke.gif</icon>
</current_conditions>
<forecast_information>
    <forecast0>
        <day>ಶನಿ.</day>
        <condition>ಬಹುಪಾಲು ಬಿಸಿಲು</condition>
        <low>25</low>
        <high>36</high>
        <icon>mostly_sunny.gif</icon>
    </forecast0>
    <forecast1>
        <day>ರ.</day>
        <condition>ಶುಭ್ರ</condition>
        <low>25</low>
        <high>35</high>
        <icon>sunny.gif</icon>
    </forecast1>
    <forecast2>
        <day>ಸೋ.</day>
        <condition>ಬಹುಪಾಲು ಬಿಸಿಲು</condition>
        <low>25</low>
        <high>36</high>
        <icon>mostly_sunny.gif</icon>
    </forecast2>
    <forecast3>
        <day>ಮಂ.</day>
        <condition>ಬಹುಪಾಲು ಬಿಸಿಲು</condition>
        <low>26</low>
        <high>33</high>
        <icon>mostly_sunny.gif</icon>
    </forecast3>
</forecast_information>
```

Comment: Hai prabhu M,I want to get the parsed xml files of various cities.Look at the URL http://192.168.1.31:81/Udayavani/android/weather/weather.php?city=mumbai". Here whenever I click on the particular city which is there back in my listview,I want the particular city parsed XMl file.If you are still having doubt then please let me know.

Comment: Vivek, you have given a local ip address.. only you can access the 192.168 address.. If you have a public address, or if you can copy paste the contents of that URL it would be helpful

Comment: @ ydntn-I have edited my answer for the actual xml contents.Please hava a look.Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the solution.I am declaring an array of places called StateNames[].And from my ListView class I am passing putExtra("id",pos) to the class where I have declared my array,and I am accessing it through the following:

```
String actualUrl="http://192.168.1.31:81/Udayavani/android/weather/weather.php?city=";     
private String[] StateNames={..,..,..};
//In OnCreate()
    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    id= b.getInt("id");
    String myURL=actualUrl+StateNames[id];
   try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Send URL to parse XML Tags */
        URL sourceUrl = new URL(myURL);

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXMLHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXMLHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use List view  instead of scroll view.  Using  onListItemClick() method of list view, get the particular list item(city in ur case) clicked and pass it as a parameter to ur function(which should be able to get xml file of  the city u passed to the url). For more info on list view [see this](http://saigeethamn.blogspot.com/2010/04/simple-listview-android-developer.html)

Comment: -Apologies for not making you clear with my question.To be simple could you please tell me how to parse multiple xml files?